# Calculate total using hidden field value instead of checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a jQuery script that calculates the total value of checkboxes onclick. I want to use the checkbox value as the `item name` instead and use a hidden field to get the value. Is there a way for me to attach a hidden field to a corresponding checkbox and calculate the value of the hidden field instead?

Here's a [fiidle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLnroomd/) of what I want to happen. Here's my jQuery:

```
function total(frm) {
    var tot = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
        if (frm.elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (frm.elements[i].checked) tot += Number(frm.elements[i].value) * Number(frm.elements[i+1].value);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("totalDiv").firstChild.data = "PHP" + tot;
}
```

```html
<li>
    <label>        
        <input type="checkbox" name="drink[]" value="DrinkName1" onclick="total(this.form);"/>
        Sample Item
        <input min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" onclick="total(this.form);"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="drinkprice" value="12">
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>        
        <input type="checkbox" name="drink[]" value="DrinkName2" onclick="total(this.form);"/>
         Sample Item
         <input min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" onclick="total(this.form);"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="drinkprice" value="6">
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>        
        <input type="checkbox" name="drink[]" value="DrinkName3" onclick="total(this.form);"/>
 Sample Item
        <input min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" onclick="total(this.form);"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="drinkprice" value="4">
    </label>
</li>
<p>Total</p>
<div id="totalDiv">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use extra hidden `input` elements to achieve this. Instead you can add your own `data-*` attribute to the checkboxes to hold the individual prices. You can also add classes to the input elements to group them together to make the calculation logic easier. From there it's a simple loop to total up the selected items.

Finally note that it is also much better practice to use unobtrusive Javascript to attach your event handlers instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes, and you should also use the `change` event of the checkboxes to accommodate those who navigate using the keyboard.

With all that said, this should achieve what you require:

```
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="drink[]" class="drink" value="DrinkName3" data-price="4" /> Sample Item
        <input min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" />
    </label>
</li>
```

```js
$('.quantity, .drink').change(calculateTotal);

function calculateTotal() {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form'), total = 0;
    $form.find('.drink:checked').each(function() {
        total += $(this).data('price') * parseInt($(this).next('.quantity').val() || 0, 10);
    });
    $('#totalDiv').text(total);
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zLnroomd/2/)

Comment: oh my god. IVE BEEN STUCK with this for days! Didn't that the solution would be this simple! Thanks! one more question though, what if I had multiple name arrays? for example, one array would be **name="drink"** and another set would be **name="dessert"**?

Comment: Never mind me. I interpreted it as a name instead of a class. Problem Solved. THANKS!

Comment: Oops the total is not updating in the [live] site (http://pizzarepublic.ph/2016/order-combo) if it's not much of a hassle could you kindly check? I'm sorry im pretty much in a brick wall right now and my lack of background in jquery is pretty much effin me up. thank you very

Comment: Check the console, you're getting an error on each checkbox click: `Uncaught ReferenceError: total is not defined`

Comment: I'm sorry but i do not understand what it means. I admit jquery is not my strength. Will continue finding solution

Comment: The error basically means that the `total` variable is not defined in the scope where you're attempting to use it.

Answer (score 0):

using html5, you're allowed to add custom data attributes to your elements, such as

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sample" name="drink[]" value="Drink1" data-item-price="12">
```

(to be valid, they need to start with `data-*`, however in practise, it's not necessary in any browser)

to get an attribute from an element is quite straight forward:

```
document.getElementById("cnt").getAttribute("data-item-price")
```

in your specific case:

```
function total(frm) 
{
    var tot = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
        if (frm.elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (frm.elements[i].checked) tot += 
                Number(frm.elements[i].getAttribute("data-item-price") * Number(frm.elements[i+1].value);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("totalDiv").firstChild.data = "PHP" + tot;
}
```

Comment: `using html5, you're allowed to add custom attributes to your elements` This is not true. Adding your own custom attributes as you are will make your HTML invalid. You can only add you own custom meta data in `data-*` attributes.